# PHP PDO drivers

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-connection

I just start learning about PDO, I need some help, I Installed PHPStorm, and I just start using it too, I already have a datbase on phpMyAdmin, I made this code, but it gives me an error

```
    <?php
try {
    $handler = new PDO ('mysql:localost;dbname=Database', 'root', 'password');
    $handler -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOExeption $e)
{
    die('Sorry, Database problem');
}
$query = $handler->query('select * from users');
while($r= $query->fetch())
{
    echo $r['name'];
}
?>
```

here is the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected' in C:\Users\user1\PhpstormProjects\PDO\pdo.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\user1\PhpstormProjects\PDO\pdo.php(11): PDO->query('select * from u...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\user1\PhpstormProjects\PDO\pdo.php on line 11.
>   Any help?

thanks in advance :).

Comment: @CD001 Lol, I feel so stupid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure your database actually exists and that there are no spelling mistakes in your connection code.

**Edit 1**

I also noticed this issue with your connection I'm not sure if this is what is causing it but you need `mysql:host=` not just `mysql:localhost`. Also you have a spelling mistake *localost*.

Change this,

```
$handler = new PDO ('mysql:localost;dbname=Database', 'root', 'password');
```

To,

```
$handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDb', $username, $password);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the handler declaration for this:

```
$handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
```

where myDatabase is the one you will be using as default..